# Reading an array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to read an array and echo one of the variables in the array, like this:

```
foreach($result->http_response_body as $obj)    {
echo $obj->items['address'];
}
```

The array looks like this when i print it:

```
    stdClass Object
(
[http_response_body] => stdClass Object
    (
        [total_count] => 1322
        [items] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [created_at] => Thu, 15 Jan 2015 08:35:06 GMT
                        [tag] => *
                        [id] => 54b77bba55edfbe50e662d3a
                        [address] => xxxx@xxxx.xx
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [created_at] => Thu, 15 Jan 2015 08:34:40 GMT
                        [tag] => *
                        [id] => 54b77ba055edfbe50e662cf6
                        [address] => xxxx@xxxx.xx
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [created_at] => Thu, 15 Jan 2015 08:31:56 GMT
                        [tag] => *
                        [id] => 54b77afc55edfbe50e662b0d
                        [address] => xxxx@xxxx.xx
                    )
```

But with my script i het this message:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xxxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxx.xx/public_html/MailGun/watchUnsubscribes.php on line 27

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the code to this:

```
foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $obj) {
    echo $obj->address;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do this instead:

```
foreach($result->http_response_body->items as $obj)    {
echo (string)$obj->address;
}
```

Comment: The provided code does not solve the problem as the author wants all  response items, not just the first one.